# Evaluating a piece of string as code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Take a string like `"4 / 10 + 5 x 3"`

how would you parse the string in Ruby and evaluate the math?

Note: Hopefully, the solution doesn't involve regex if possible

Comment: I'd insure that string is safe and call `eval` with it.

Comment: I just realised I can parse the x into a *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "4 / 10 + 5 x 3"
eval(str.tr("x","*"))
```

If you want to keep the `x` you can translate it using tr.

`eval` can run anything, so don't try this with user input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) to evaluate a string as Ruby code.

> `eval(string [, binding [, filename [,lineno]]])`
>
> Evaluates the Ruby expression(s) in string. If binding is given, which
>   must be a Binding object, the evaluation is performed in its context.
>   If the optional filename and lineno parameters are present, they will
>   be used when reporting syntax errors.

In your case

```
string = '4 / 10 + 5 * 3'
eval(string)
```

Keep in mind that the string you posted is not valid Ruby code. In fact, `x` is invalid, the correct operator is `*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "4 / 10 + 5 x 3"
result = eval(str)
```

Comment: Won't work - `x` is not a Ruby operator

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will throw a Syntax error since you're trying to multiply using the character `x`.
You should use `*` operator.

After that it's simple by using `eval()`. But normally this should be refrained from.

```
result = eval("4 / 10 + 5 * 3")
```

For math parsing I would look into this [gem](https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku), haven't tried it myself but seems better than raw eval.